# Is a bijective graph homomorphism also an automorphism?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $f$ be a map from a finite graph $G$ to itself.

Then

- $f$ is an homomorphism if $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are adjacent for all adjacent vertices $x$ and $y$ in $G$.
- $f$ is an automorphism if, for all vertices $x$ and $y$ in $G$, $x$ and $y$ are adjacent if and only if $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are adjacent.

If $f$ is a bijective homomorphism, how do I show it is also an automorphism? I've seen a proof of the equivalent statement for groups but I can't see how to translate it to the language of graph theory.

Comment: $f$ gives you a bijection $g$ from the cartesian product of the set of vertices with itself (pairs of vertices). In particular, since $f$ is a homomorphism $g$ restricts to an injective function on the set of edges (which is a subset of the set of pairs of vertices). An injective function from a finite set to itself is bijective. Therefore, $g$ restricted to the set of edges is bijective. Hence $f$ is an automorphism.

Comment: When you say $f$ is a bijection, do you mean on verticies, on edges, or both?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $G$ has $m$ edges and $f: G \to G$ is a bijective homomorphism.
Then each pair of adjacent vertices determines an edge on the image of $f$.
Thus there exist $m$ edges in the image of $f$, which are all distinct because $f$ is injective.
Let $x$ and $y$ be non-adjacent vertices in $G$.
Then $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ are also non-adjacent, otherwise the image of $f$, which is contained in $G$, would have $m + 1$ edges.
Hence $f$ is an automorphism.